# Why when I trigger a "change" event on a check box the event object is not updated with the new state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 elements. For some reason, I'm not able to trigger a change event on a checkbox and to pass the information about the new state of the checkbox to the event method.

Why when the event is called the checked property doesn't display correctly?

```js
// this works perfectly fine. UI updates. The event method is called and the event e contains the new checked property
$('#mycheckbox').on('change', this.onCheckboxClicked.bind(this));

// this works only partially. UI gets updated. The event methos is called but the event e doesn't contain the checked property.
$('#sometext').on('click', () => $('#mycheckbox').trigger('change'));

function onCheckboxClicked(e) {
  // display true when i click on the checkbox but false when i click on the span. Why ?
  console.log($(e.target).prop('checked'));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
<span id="sometext">My Text</span>
```

Comment: Why are you indicating as a class? - `$('.mycheckbox').trigger('change')`. This is `id="mycheckbox"`.

Comment: sorry . a typo. it's not a class but an id. but that is not the issue

Comment: Do you just want to check the box on click?

Comment: no i want to check it when i click on the checkbox AND when i click on the span label using the same event METHOD

Comment: `change` doesn't tell the checkbox what to change, just that a change happened. It would be a good event to trigger if you'd already changed the `checked` property and want to tell others about it. If you want its `checked` property to change, you should call `click`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are triggering a `change` event but that will not update the `checked` state of the checkbox.
If you change `$('#mycheckbox').trigger('change')` to `$('#mycheckbox').trigger('click')` it should work.

I must say though that you can just use:

```html
<label for="mycheckbox">My Text</label>
```

to achieve the same effect.

Comment: No. The e.target is the checkbox. That's why i call trigger. trigger() emulates a real click on the checkbox. You can double check

Comment: What do you mean with click. It seems to me that if i trigger click instead the checkbox UI is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('#mycheckbox').trigger('change')` to `$('#mycheckbox').trigger('click')`.

In order to provide a better user experience for those without the use of a mouse, browsers have been developed to **fire** the `onclick` event even if the **click** occurs with a `keyboard`.

For this reason, jQuery's

1. `click` event will fire even if the checkbox is clicked by using the keyboard's spacebar.
2. `change` will fire every time the checkbox's state changes.

The checkbox just happens to be the special case where change and click are interchangeable because you can't fire the change event without also triggering click.

```js
$('#mycheckbox').on('change', this.onCheckboxClicked.bind(this));

$('#sometext').on('click', () => $('#mycheckbox').trigger('click'));

function onCheckboxClicked(e) {
  console.log($(e.target).prop('checked'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
<span id="sometext">My Text</span>
```

Comment: Sorry. This doesnt work for me. Probably because i have jquery 3.5 or because I use a sort of bootstrap styled check box ? but shouldnt be a problem. It works if I use a promise

Comment: Updated my CDN to jQuery 3.5.1, seems to work @ClaudioFerraro

Comment: No idea. I'll make some researches before approving an answer

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I did this. Don't know why but the proposed approach with click using jquery 3.5 and a kind of bootstrap styled input didn't work.

```
$('#sometext').on('click', () => Promise.resolve().then(() => $('#mycheckbox').trigger('change')));
```

**UPDATE**

Seems like when another EventHandler is attached to the same element, for example if I have this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" />
<span id="sometext" class="myspan">My Text</span>
```

and then

```
$('#mycheckbox').on('change', this.onCheckboxClicked.bind(this));

// even though .myspan is a different class, the event is attached to the 
// same DOM object which not only generates the issue described in the 
// question but also will nullify the solution in the answer proposed.
$('.myspan').on('click', this.onAnotherMethodClicked.bind(this));

$('#sometext').on('click', () => $('#mycheckbox').trigger('change'));
```

Comment: `$('.myspan')` and `$('#sometext')` both point to the same DOM element. The first accesses it using the class name, the second one using the id. So you're attaching two click event handlers to your span, which is perfectly valid. I assume that in each handler you're running some code that negates the other. If you want better help you should make sure to post your complete code and not just the part that you _think_ is relevant.